# How to connect with udp in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android.I need to know how to connect (communicate)  with PC’s UDP server  with android client.Can anyone give a simple example ( Guide me to understand)

Answer (score 2):

With Android you have a broad range of packages you can work with so most existing examples of a UDP client/server for Java should provide sufficient.. Try taking a look at something simple and expand from there.  The only thing to note is to try and follow the Android developer guidelines when implementing any code for maximum efficiency.

[Simple Java UDP example](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/)
[More Java socket examples](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~troy/spring05/cs450/sockets/socket.html)